Using withAuthenitcationProps for every page.tsx for Amazon Cognito
I have a nextjs app and the following is a sample structure of my project:
├── README.md
├── amplify
│   ├── #current-cloud-backend
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── auth
│   ├── backend
│   ├── cli.json
│   ├── hooks
│   └── team-provider-info.json
├── app
│   ├── ConfigureAmplify.tsx
│   ├── amplifyconfiguration.json
│   ├── aws-exports.js
│   ├── dashboard
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── lib
│   ├── page.tsx
│   └── ui
├── next-env.d.ts
├── next.config.js
├── node_modules

and my /app/page.tsx is:
"use client";


import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import type { WithAuthenticatorProps } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { Button, withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import config from './amplifyconfiguration.json';
Amplify.configure(config);

export function Page({ signOut, user }: WithAuthenticatorProps) {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col p-6">
      <h1>MAIN PAGE/LOGIN PAGE</h1>
      <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
      <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</Button>
    </main>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(Page);

If I go to the route localhost:3000 I have to log in.
But if I go to the route localhost:3000/dashboard the dashboard page will load even if I am not logged in.
Is there anyway to fix this?

Hi I found the solution for anyone else that runs into a similar issue you want to use the import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'; component in the app/layout.tsx not page.tsx because it applies that layout to all the child components.
